# Given a Python *.py file what's the canonical way to determine the dotted import path for that file, programmatically?

Tags: python, python-import

Suppose you get a `pathlib.Path` that points to a `*.py` file.

And also suppose that this **is** a resource you could `import` in another Python file, given the appropriate import path, because your `sys.path` allows for it.

How do you determine the dotted import path to use in `import`, from just the python file?

Unlike most of the import-related questions, this is NOT about the path from one Python file to another within a directory hierarchy, **it is really more about the import path you could specify in the REPL from anywhere** to import that module and that's affected by `sys.path` contents.

##### Example:

```
$test_366_importpath$ tree -I __pycache__
.
└── sub
    └── somemodule.py
```

##### somemodule.py

```
"some module"

class Foo:
    "Foo class"
```

If I start python at that location, because `sys.path` gets the current directory, this works:

`from sub.somemodule import Foo`

`sub.somemodule` is what I am interested in.

However, if the `sys.path` gets altered, then I can use a different import path.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/Users/me/explore/test_366_importpath/sub")
from somemodule import Foo
```

(note:  I wouldn't be doing this "for real", neither the sys.path.insert, nor varying the dotted path I'd use, see @CryptoFool's comment.  This is just a convient way to show sys.path impact)

##### Question:

How do I determine, programmatically, that `import sub.somemodule` needs to be used as the dotted path?  Or `import somemodule` given different sys.path conditions?

Raising an ImportError or ValueError or some other exceptions if the *.py file is not importable is perfectly OK.

I'm writing a helper using

`pa_script = pathlib.Path("somemodule.py").absolute().resolve()` and then looking at `sys.path`.  Once I find that a given sys.path entry is the parent for the `pa_script`, I can use `pa_script.relative_to(parent)`.

From there it's trivial to get the import path by removing the `.py` extension and replacing `os.sep` with `.`.

Then I can feed that dotted path to `importlib`. Or paste into my code editor.

It's a bit tricky but not particularly hard.  Makes me wonder however if there isn't a builtin or canonical way however.

I can post my code, but really if there is a canonical way to do it, it would just give the wrong impression that's it's necessary to do these complicated steps.

Comment: I don't think there is any canonical way to produce such a string, and if I were trying to create one, I'd take an approach like the one you describe

Comment: Why would you ever want to sometimes import a module via `from sub.somemodule import X` and sometimes as `from somemodule import X`?  I believe that this is asking for trouble.  These aren't the same thing.  There can and will be problems if you ever mix code that is doing it two different ways.  In the example you give, why not do `sys.path.insert(0, "/Users/me/explore/test_366_importpath")` so that your code can always do `from sub.submodule import X`?  In general, any time you have to do the kind of thing you're doing, something's wrong...it's a code smell.

Comment: @CryptoFool You're right, except I only gave that as a simple *example* of the impact of sys.path contents on the import path.  sys.path.insert hacks are to be avoided at the best of times.  Point is, your dotted path *will* change depending on what's in your sys.path (at least for stuff that's not coming in through pip and `site-packages`).  So, I am not *doing what you think I am doing*, only calculating the dotted import path that could be used.  No more, no less.

Comment: @JLPeyret - I get what you're saying.  You may very well have a use case where all this makes sense.  I've done a lot of pretty crazy things with Python, including dynamic applications with various notions of my own of Python "plug-ins" and such.  I've never had to resort to this sort of thing.  Thinking back, I guess how I've avoided problems like this was to manipulate `sys.path` rather than having to contort the rest of my code to work with whatever happened to be in it.

Comment: I make liberal use of `pip install -E <some directory>` which results in stuff not in `site-packages`.  Add that and anything based on dotted paths and you have some use cases.  They are, I want to stress, more relevant to code introspection or developer tooling than anything else you'd want to write in your own code to run at production time.  For example, I was importing python files that had a `@click` CLI in them and accessing their docstring for documentation purposes.  Part of that was tracking under which dotted path the script was importable.

Answer (score 1):

Well here goes then, in case anyone needs something similar

(for Python 3.10+, but removing typehints should make it work down to much earlier 3.x versions)

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys
import os

def get_dotted_path(path_to_py: str | Path, paths: list[str] | None = None) -> str:
    """
    return a dotted-path import string from a Python filename

    if given, `paths` will be examined as if it was `sys.path` else
    `sys.path` is used to determine import points (this is to compute paths
    assuming a different sys.path context than the current one)
    )

    example:
    .../lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py => "collections"
    .../lib/python3.10/collections/abc.py => "collections.abc"

    raises ImportError if the Python script is not in sys.path or paths
    """
    parent = None
    pa_target = Path(path_to_py)
    paths = paths or sys.path

    # get the full file path AND resolve if it's a symlink
    pa_script = pa_target.absolute().resolve().absolute()

    # consider pkg/subpk/__init__.py as pkg/subpk
    if pa_script.name == "__init__.py":
        pa_script = pa_script.parent

    for path in paths:
        pa_path = Path(path)
        if pa_path in pa_script.parents:
            parent = pa_path
            break
    else:
        newline = "\n"
        raise ImportError(
            f"{pa_script} nowhere in sys.path: {newline.join([''] + paths)}"
        )

    pa_relative = pa_script.relative_to(parent)
    res = str(pa_relative).removesuffix(".py").replace(os.sep, ".")
    return res
```