# Python full module path of a function

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

Is it possible to obtain a string containing the whole namespace from which a function was imported?
I would like some code like the following:

```py
import math
import numpy

whole1 = get_whole_namespace(math.sin)
whole2 = get_whole_namespace(numpy.sin)
```

The resulting `whole1` should be the string `"math.sin"`, and the resulting `whole2` should be the string `"numpy.sin"`. Is there any standard library (or third party) functionality equivalent to the `get_whole_namespace` function in my example?

I originally thought that my desired result should be available in some dunder method or attribute. But the `__name__` attribute of both `math.sin` and `numpy.sin` is the string `"sin"`.
The `math.sin` function also has a `__qualname__` attribute (which is the string `"sin"`), and a `__module__` attribute (which is the string `"math"`).
The `numpy.sin` function does not have either `__qualname__` or `__math__` attributes.

I am using Python 3.10.6 and NumPy 1.23.4.

Comment: Note that „namespace from which a function was imported“ isn’t what qualname/name/module mean (it’s where the function was *defined*) and the notion seems roughly as ill-defined as the related „variable name of a value“. A single object may have zero, one or arbitrary many names and subsequently just as many name(spaces) from which to import it.

Comment: Say you wrote `from numpy import sin` what should `get_whole_namespace` return then?  What about `from numpy import sin as sin2`?  i.e. are expect the path you’d have to use with importlib or Django’s “import by string” utility function?  Or should it reflect what *you* used to import those functions?

Comment: @JLPeyret What I had in mind is the "original path" i.e., `get_whole_namespace` used on `sin2` obtained by `from numpy import sin as sin2` should still be `"numpy.sin"`.
Or another more common example: if I did `import numpy as np`, the result of `get_whole_namespace(np.sin)` should still be `"numpy.sin"`, not `"np.sin"`.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, you are probably right, I didn't think of it that way, that my question was similar to the "variable name of a value" concept. I guess I was confused by the fact that functions and classes have a `__name__` attribute, some of them also have a `__module__` attribute, so I thought that somehow it was possible to keep track of the whole import path.

BTW, if you read my answer to JLPeyret, you will see that I am interested in the original definition of a function, not in the arbitrary names assigned to a function object.

Comment: In that case this Q of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71415779/given-a-python-py-file-whats-the-canonical-way-to-determine-the-dotted-import might be of interest.  If you could reliably get at the `__file__` relating to the function’s module then you could determine its import path.

Comment: @JLPeyret thanks! It seems these things are more complex than they seem, since you also had to create your own custom solution!

Comment: @EnricoGandini  that’s one way to consider it.  Another is to consider that maybe what I hacked together there was somewhat of an anti-pattern that no one should be using. Or an x-y problem.  And… not sure how functions based on C extensions would behave.